# install pyquery for python

Tags: python, windows, versioninfo

I want to install pyquery I have lxml-2.2.2 folder I dnt know how to proceed I have tried

```
  setup.py install
```

in cmd prompt

```
  C:\Python27\Scripts>setup.py install
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\setup.py", line 27, in <module>
  import versioninfo
  ImportError: No module named versioninfo
```

I get this error can any one guide me to install pyquery thanks in advance

Comment: I've downloaded the latest `pyquery` zipped source (version 1.2.4) and I cannot find the line `import versioninfo` anywhere in the source files. Can you copy and paste in your question the code from the `setup.py` file you're trying to run?

Comment: In the example you gave, you are running setup.py from c:\Python27\Scripts. You need to find the directory to which you extracted pyquery and run setup.py from there.

Comment: Thanks I have installed pyquery I have downloaded lxml-2.2.2 I installed it using easy_install and then I did the same for pyquery. I thank all for helping me.